# How to receive reply via sms using any amazon service

Tags: email, amazon-s3, sms, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm using the amazon SNS(Simple Notification Service) service to publish SMS/Emails but I did not found any way to receive reply from user.

Any user can subscribe or unsubscribe to receive messages but he/she can not send any reply to sender.

Please suggest any idea to implement the logic to receive reply via amazon service.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the reply of SMS that sent to a mobile device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143366/how-can-i-get-the-reply-of-sms-that-sent-to-a-mobile-device)

Answer (score -1):

SNS is for notifications and you <del>can</del> can't receive the replies.
Instead you can use Simple Email Service (SES) : http://aws.amazon.com/ses/

If you need email template management, mail-merge variables etc (more specific email needs), you can consider third party services like: Mailchimp or Mandril.

Comment: SNS does *not* allow you to receive replies. Though their documentation says "send and receive SMS", what they actually mean (in that document) is "send SMS from AWS" and "receive [that] SMS on a phone". They recommend Twilio for 2-way SMS.